# Add Tab Bar Programmatically to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a `TabBarController` in my `Main.storyboard` file.
In my `Upload.storyboard` I am presenting a ViewController from the `Main.storyboard` file, however, it doesn't contain the tab bar.

The `viewProfile` button should go to a tab called `Sharks` and within that present a view controller based on data gathered in the `Upload.storyboard` (modal view).

Can I add the tab bar programmatically or am I not properly presenting the correct VC?

```
// MARK: - Actions
@IBAction func viewProfileButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let stb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let sharkProfile = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sharkProfile") as! SharkProfileTableViewController
    self.present(sharkProfile, animated: true) {
        // add tab bar here?
    }
}
```

[image: TabBarController.swift]

[image: UploadConfirmationViewController.swift]

Comment: What do you want to happen here? Are you *starting* with a Tab Bar, tapping "viewProfile", and then you want to show "SharkProfile" *in place of* the current view for that Tab? Do you want "SharkProfile" to slide-in from the right like a typical Navigation Controller? Or do you want "SharkProfile" to have its own, separate Tab Bar?

Comment: The application begins with a tab bar - but then I'm presenting a modal view with no tab bar.  In this modal view tapping viewProfile should present the SharkProfile as it is the in Main.storyboard (with a tab bar).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is present the tab bar view controller, not the view controller that is embedded in it

Answer (score 0):

One method is to create a Delegate Protocol to allow a tap on `View Profile` button to "call back" to the View Controller that presented it. When that callback is received, the VC sets the "current" tab.

It will look something like this:

```
// define "call back" delegate protocol
protocol EncounterUploadedDelegate : class {
    func didTapSharkProfileButton()
}
```

The `Encounter` view controller will need to conform to that protocol:

```
class EncounterViewController: UIViewController, EncounterUploadedDelegate {

    // the normal stuff for this VC and all the other code for it
    // ...

    // conform to the protocol
    func didTapSharkProfileButton() -> Void {
        // when we get this call-back, switch to the Shark Profile tab
        // tabs are zero-based, so assuming "SharkProfile" is
        // is the 4th tab...
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3
    }

    // assuming a "Show Modal" segue named "ShowEncounterUploadSegue" is used
    //  to present the Modal View
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowEncounterUploadSegue" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! TabModalVC
            vc.encounterDelegate = self
        }
    }

}
```

The view controller to be presented as modal:

```
class TabModalVC: UIViewController {
    weak var encounterDelegate: EncounterUploadedDelegate?

    @IBAction func profileButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        // dismiss self (the modal view)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        // this will call back to the delegate, if one has been assigned
        encounterDelegate?.didTapSharkProfileButton()
    }

}
```

Hope that all makes sense :)